# Hover effects not working with IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, hover, doctype

I used CSS for a color change on hover for a table

```
#tabb tbody tr:hover td{
    color:#006;
    background:#d0e4f2;
}
```

This works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but the hover effect does not happen in Internet Explorer 8.

Is there a way to make this effect work with IE8 as well?

Comment: Works absolutely fine in IE8. Validate your html code.

Comment: @AR: found the problem, with @thirtydot's help - a missing DOCTYPE.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

That *should* work fine in IE8.

A stab in the dark:

Make sure you have [a doctype](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/) as the very first line of your HTML that triggers Standards Mode, such as:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

In [Quirks Mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode), IE emulates version 5.5, which does not support `:hover` on elements other than `a`.

Comment: I did not have that line. Now it works! Thanks, I will read up about doctype, had no idea.

Comment: I had my doctype in my jsp, but then took things out for troubleshooting something else.  You nailed it!  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

IE8 is not the usual culprit for `:hover` problems. If you can't get it to work, there's always jQuery!

```
$("#tabb tbody tr").hover(
    function() {
        $("this").children("td").css( { 'background-color': '#d0e4f2', 'color': '#006' } );
    },
    function() {
        $("this").children("td").css( { ... } );
    }
);
```

Comment: not a terrible option, but shouldn't be nessisary, and over very large tables, will have some performance issues.

Comment: If you decide to take the jQuery route, you could also create a `.highlight` class in your CSS, and then use jQuery's `toggleClass()` function, rather than hardcoding the CSS attributes into your statement. A better solution if you're willing to add the extra code to your CSS IMO.

Comment: @Patricia - Good point about performance. Too many people rely on javascript in unnecessary situations without thinking about the consequences.

Answer (score 0):

my guess is something wonky in your html code for the table.  as you can see on this quick and dirty fiddle,   your css is a-ok:

http://jsfiddle.net/PwZsN/