# doctype html breaks layout

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css

I am trying to replicate layout of html5doctor.com. I have IE8 installed here.
I am able to produce following output:

[image]

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"  href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
    </div>
    <div id="nav">
        <div id="navmenus">
            <ul id="navmenulist">                   
                <li class="menu" id="id1">
                    <a href="#">Home</a>
                <li class="menu">
                    <a href="#">Products</a>
                <li class="menu">
                    <a href="#">About Us</a>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="content" >
        <div id="article"></div>
        <div id="sidebar"></div>    
    </div>      
    <div id="footer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
/*I have added CSS Reset from http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
       Just deleted it for simplicity 
*/

body
{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;    
    background-color:#E8E8E8;
    text-align:center;
}

#header
{
    background-color:#1F7ADB;
    width:100%;
    height:150px;
}

#nav
{
    background-color:#1F7ADB;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;  
}

#navmenus
{
    background-color:#14B3F7;
    width:900px;
    text-align:left;    
}

li.menu
{
    list-style:none;
    display:inline;     
    height:35px;
    padding:12px;   
}

li.menu:hover
{
    background-color:yellow;        
}

li.menu a
{   
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:18px; 
}

#content
{
    width:900px;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    height:1300px;

}
```

Notice `li.menu:hover` in above CSS. It is not working in IE8. So I added `<!DOCTYPE html>` as suggested at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269831/hover-effects-not-working-with-ie8).

It made hover work but now it broke the layout as follows:

[image]

I will like to get result that will work on IE8 first and then will like to learn work around that will work consistently in major (may not be in IE6) browser. And will glad to stick to CSS and HTML (no script). And above all will like to learn whats exactly wrong here.

Comment: Try adding `#navmenus, #content { margin: 0 auto; }`

Comment: try margin:0 auto; instead of center

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `text-align:center;` from the `body` and use `margin:auto` for the block elements you want centered in the page..

The elements that require it are `#navmenus` and `#content`, so

```
#navmenus
{
    background-color:#14B3F7;
    width:900px;
    margin:0 auto;   
}

#content
{
    width:900px;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    height:1300px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Comment: well it worked but some more layout is obscured by doctype, will work on that, thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

I would update the CSS for the content area to this:

```
#content
{
    width:900px;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    height:1300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Using the margin will center this element, rather than trying to use text-align on the parent element.