# Filter opacity not working

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, opacity

For some reason filter: opacity is not working in IE8. I haven't used it in a while but it's always worked, I have no idea what the problem is. Also, firebug is not showing the filter rule at all, just normal opacity.

Any ideas?

```
ul.products-grid img:hover {

    opacity: .8;
    filter:alpha(opacity=80);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the tag is

```
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=80);
```

try this out

Answer (score 1):

In IE8, you may also need;

`-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=80)";`

You may as well want to take a look at [Cross Browser Opacity](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/cross-browser-opacity/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ul.products-grid img:hover {
    opacity: .8; /* Standards Compliant Browsers */
    filter:alpha(opacity=80); /* IE 7 and Earlier */
    /* Next 2 lines IE8 */
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=80)";
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=80);
}
```

if you want your page to `validate`, separate your standards stylesheet from your IE stylesheet by using an if IE statement like below:

```
<!--[if IE]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="stylesheetname.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Also check if your page is being rendered in quirks mode in IE. I think IE8 may not support the :hover pseudo class on arbitrary elements unless it's in standards compliance mode.

Similar situation and explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269831/hover-effects-not-working-with-ie8).

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS works fine. Check out the demo here, http://jsfiddle.net/e26Pz/2/

Maybe problem could be on `DOC` type. In the example I used `<!DOCTYPE html>`

What `Doc` type are you using?

**Full demo code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title> - jsFiddle demo</title>
  <style type='text/css'>
    img:hover {    
       opacity: 0.4;
       filter:alpha(opacity=40);
    }
  </style>

</head>
<body>
     <img src="https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn1/69651_408104205949356_2097957740_n.jpg" />      
</body>   
</html>
```

Comment: Nice fiddle, but did you test that in IE8? For me, jsfiddle.net doesn't even seem to be working in IE8.

Comment: I checked on IE8 and worked for me. Try this link, http://fiddle.jshell.net/e26Pz/2/show/

Comment: Yeah, that one works fine for me in IE8. Now I'm confused however, as most sources seem to claim that IE8 needs that -ms-filter rule.