# IE8 bug - CSS "a:hover" attribute not working

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, css-selectors

I have a list of anchor links that have associated :hover attributes - really simple. The CSS works fine in IE7 and all other browsers, but not in IE8.

```css
.header-nav ul li a:hover {
     border-bottom: 1px dotted #fff;
}
```

I tried changing my doctype declaration from HTML5 to HTML4 strict and nothing changed - any ideas?

Thanks!

EDIT: associated HTML:

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="http://www.google.com/">Getting Started</a>
    </li><li><a href="http://www.google.com/">Refill</a>
    </li><li><a href="http://www.google.com/">Status</a>
    </li><li><a href="http://www.google.com/">Services</a>
    </li><li><a href="http://www.google.com/">Conditions</a></li>
</ul>
```

Regular CSS:

```css
.header-nav ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding-left:25px;
    position: absolute; 
    top: 10px;
    *top: 15px;
    left: 0;        
}

.header-nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    zoom: 1; *display: inline;      /* Fix for IE7 */
    padding: 0 40px;
}

.header-nav ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 23px;
    font-size: 18px;
    position: relative;
    top: 7px;
    *top: 2px;  /* IE7 */
    color: #fff;    
}
```

Again, to be clear, this works in IE7 but NOT in IE8, which is the confusing part...

Comment: check -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269831/hover-effects-not-working-with-ie8

Comment: Syntax looks good to me. Make sure your anchor element isn't missing quotes or a closing tag.

Comment: @ChristopherMarshall, haha hey man.

Comment: Can you post *all* of the relevant code - `:hover` should work fine in IE 8

Comment: Fairly confident there is nothing wrong with the code as displayed. can you reproduce the issue in a jsfiddle? PS, keep the HTML5 doctype.

Comment: Oh hi there! I remember you!

Comment: Working on a jsfiddle, I will say that changing the doctype (which is what I thought was the issue) hasn't done anything

Comment: Press F12.  Are you in standards or quirks mode?  It'll say at the top of the screen.  [Instructions with pictures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/hh779632.aspx)

Comment: I'm in IE8 standards mode.

Comment: What exactly DO you see then?

Comment: The code you posted works fine in IE8-mode: http://fiddle.jshell.net/NpjXP/show/  [separate edit link since jsfiddle no longer works in IE8-mode](http://jsfiddle.net/NpjXP)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was due to the **position:relative** on the **.header-nav ul li a** tag... I have no idea why IE8 couldn't handle this (and IE7 could!). My fix was to simulate the relative positioning by just making the line-height attribute larger (and adding a *line-height to account for differences in the IE7 rendering).

If anyone has any insight on why this issue was caused I'd love to hear it!

Hope this helps future confused front-end devs that are stuck accounting for older versions of IE...

Answer (score 1):

I has this issue in IE8, and the above solution did not work.

In the end the reason the above did not work is something to do with the fact that I am using datatables and I am using ajax to get the data asynchronously. The hover works fine if I switch the table to using static data, but does not work with ajax.

I am guessing its something to do with IE not being able to apply styles to dynamically added row or something.

It works fine in Chrome...!

Answer (score 0):

Below a 100% working solution.

```
.navigation li ul { opacity: 0; visibility: hidden; filter: alpha(opacity=0); // for ie8 and lower }

.navigation li:hover ul{ opacity: 1 !important; visibility: visible; filter: none !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add following line to the top of your html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```