# Why does this work in firefox and chrome, but not IE8

Tags: html, css, iframe

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<style>

.box{
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
}

a:hover + .box,.box:hover{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
}

</style>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<a href="Spanishwordoftheweek.pdf"><img src = "spanishwordbanner.png"  /></a><div class="box"><iframe src="Spanishwordoftheweek.pdf" width = "800" height = "1050"> <p> Your browser does not support iframe. </p></iframe></div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is a simple picture that displays a pdf on hover. It works perfectly in chrome and firefox, but not in IE8. Does anybody know why?

Thanks

Comment: In what way does it not work in IE8?

Comment: When you hover on the image the iframe never shows up.

Comment: Any javascript errors if you open developer tools (F12) and "start debugging"?

Comment: There isn't any javascript, the code above is the only code I have. I am just trying to get this piece to work before I implement it on my site

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in internet explorer where 'some' elements do not support hover. Perhaps [this stack overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269831/hover-effects-not-working-with-ie8) relates to your problem.

EDIT: Found [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17934593/ie8-bug-css-ahover-attribute-not-working)

Comment: It also says it's not allowing my webpage to run scripts or ActiveX controls that could access your computer. I didn't think that was problem but it seems like some people have trouble with the same thing.