# this code not work in ie ( hover to show element )

Tags: css

This code not work in ie ( hover to show element )

Please help me about css thank you.

```
<style type="text/css">
body {
  font: 14px/1.4 arial;
}
.imgWrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 140px;
  height: 112px;
}
.imgDescription {
  margin-top: -90px;
  margin-left: 144px;
  width: 728px;
  height: 90px;
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  -moz-opacity: 0.00;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}
.imgWrap:hover .imgDescription {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  -moz-opacity: 1.00;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}
</style>

<div class="imgWrap">
  <img src="http://3.envato-static.com/assets/header-footer/microlancer/web-development-services-e546173320569b008737e36c59b25782.jpg" alt="polaroid" />
  <div class="imgDescription"><img src="http://static.adzerk.net/Advertisers/d893babe671c41118c1fece177e0a21a.jpg"/></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What version of IE? What doesn't work exactly?

Comment: I don't believe `-moz-opacity` is supported in IE7/8 (maybe even newer)

Comment: You should always place the standard property **after** the vendor prefix. Thus opacity: 0; should appear **after** -moz-opacity: 0.00; and opacity: 1; after -moz-opacity: 1.00; You also have position absolute on the imgDescription style without providing a position, I.e. top and left properties. I suggest you remove it as I have seen browser bugs with one missing, never mind both - and it's not doing anything anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should avoid the filters, it's not working for you. Also, for me, that image inside `.imgDescription` didn't like being linked to.

I removed all the opacity and filter information (you don't need it if you have absolutely positioned item with a hidden visibility) and changed the `background-color` of `.imgDescription` so you can see that it works.

IE 7, 8 (using IE 9 rendering as) work fine (though IE 7 has poor positioning of the `div`, it still does work.

http://jsfiddle.net/7Jvcy/

To test the output in IE 7 and 8: http://fiddle.jshell.net/7Jvcy/show/

```
.imgDescription {
  margin-top: -90px;
  margin-left: 144px;
  width: 728px;
  height: 90px;
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
    background-color: #f00;
}
.imgWrap:hover .imgDescription {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: You can use `opacity`, but using a Microsoft `filter` seemed to break it for IE 7 and 8.

Answer (score 0):

I think that IE have some problems with apply a style to child of a metaclass.
You can use a js, maybe only for IE, to have the same effect.

javascript (need jQuery):

```
jQuery('.imgWrap').hover(function () {
  jQuery(this).addClass('hover');
}, function () {
  jQuery(this).removeClass('hover');
});
```

css that change:

```
.imgWrap:hover .imgDescription,  .imgWrap.hover .imgDescription
{
visibility: visible;
opacity: 1;
-moz-opacity: 1.00;
filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/tYG4V/)

Answer (score -1):

You can add the HTML4.1 doctype to your HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

Or you can just try the HTML5 doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Comment: :hover has been supported for non-link elements since Internet Explorer 7 - see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover. More to the point, I'm not sure how changing the doctype is supposed to add support to the browser?

Comment: @pwdst [Well it had worked for other people](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269831/hover-effects-not-working-with-ie8/6269882#6269882)

Comment: That is not what you said in either your original or edited answer. If you'd said make sure you *have* a doctype and that it is on the first line *before* any whitespace then I'd not have voted it down. Instead you recommend changing the doctype to HTML 4 and (originally) cited incorrect information. The down vote stands.