# Why is this :hover selector not working?

Tags: html, css

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong here! probably something really obvious. I am trying to change the background colour and font colour of a div on mouse hover using purely CSS/HTML

HTML:

```
<div id="cta">
    Learn More >
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#cta {
width: 65px;
border: 1px solid #183073;
border-radius: 5px;
background-color: white;
color: #183073;
font-family: Arial;
font-size: 10px;
padding: 5px;
}

#cta:hover {
background-color: #183073;
color: white;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Works here, what is your testing environment like? Waiting for a server to sync perhaps? http://jsfiddle.net/2Y6sx/

Comment: you sure not working at your side?

Comment: Working well for me also.

Comment: In this peace of code is no problem, just instead of DIV you should use A -> users want to click for more details.

Comment: your code is working fine dude:) check here http://jsfiddle.net/8db7d/

Comment: in which browser / OS you are testing... Its working fine for me too :)

Comment: may be other styles are over writing your code. try to use important keyword.

Comment: *Suresh: Never, ever use !important.

Comment: Show us what doctype you have declared

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set the `z-index` of `#cta` to something large like `99999`. If it works like that it means that you have another element covering your div and preventing the hover.

Comment: Thanks so much!! Works now silly me

Answer (score 0):

:hover will work for element of type A across Browsers.
Some browsers do not allow :hover to any DOM object and restricted only to Anchor.

Similar isssue is solved in 
[Hover effects not working with IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269831/hover-effects-not-working-with-ie8)