# button:hover not working in IE 11 compatibility mode

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to add `hover` effect to `button` tag. But it doesn't work in IE 11 (compatibility mode). I'm unable to find any reference of why it doesn't work.
What can be the workaround for this?

```css
.genericBtn {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  color: #000000;
}


.genericBtn:hover {
  background-color: grey;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<button class="genericBtn">
  <span>Hover to change</span>
</button>

<br>

<h3>This hover effect doesn't work in IE 11(compatibility mode)</h3>
```

Comment: Spotted a typo: You meant to use `#000000` (zeros), not `#OOOOOO` (alphabet "O"s)?

Comment: @Terry, Thanks, corrected the typo.

Comment: Did that typo fix ie11?

Comment: Do you have `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" >` in your `<head>`?

Comment: When I run this code snippet in IE 11, it works fine. Maybe your actual code is different from this snippet? have you tried using hex code instead of color name? like `backgorund-color: #808080;`

Comment: @developernator, No, because its a legacy application. And its supposed to be run only in compatibility mode.

Comment: @KKK, It will run in IE 11, but not when your are running IE 11 in 'compatibility view'.

Comment: _“because its a legacy application”_ - well then it should not matter too much, if it also “looks legacy”, and doesn’t provide optic sugar such as button hover effects ... // Have you tried applying the formatting to the span inside the button (if possible)?

Comment: This is probably your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269831/hover-effects-not-working-with-ie8 *"In Quirks Mode, IE emulates version 5.5, which does not support :hover on elements other than a."*

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft introduced *compatibility mode* in IE8 to emulate quirks and errors of old IEs for legacy apps.

One of these quirks is/was that `:hover` pseudoclass works only on links (`<a href=…>` tags):

```
.foo {
  color: pink;
}

.foo:hover {
  color: hotpink;
}


<a class="foo" href="https://stackoverflow.com/">Stackoverflow</a> 
will change color on hover, but
<button class="foo">Stackoverflow</button>
will stay the same
```

Browser support for [`:hover` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover):

[image: :hover browser support table]

One possible solution would be to use `<a>` with `onClick` to emulate the button behavior:

```
<a class="foo" href="#" onclick="doSomething(); return false;">Do something</a>
```

Or… just don't worry about it, i think that nobody expects fancy buttons in an app that needs IE7 rendering in 2018. ;)

Comment: Wouldn't it be `onmouseover`/`onmouseout`?

Comment: @Quentin, Thanks for the suggestions, I guess I'll need to rely on these events.

Comment: The point of compatibility mode is to make IE work with code developed for IE 4. You shouldn't need to develop new code that works with it.