# :hover pseudo state not triggering in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, hover

I have this markup

```
<button class="toggle" aria-label="Toggle">
   <div class="globe-img"></div>
</button>
```

and this SASS:

```
.globe-img {
   background-image: url('../images/globe.png');
   height: 50px;
   width: 50px;
   &:hover {
     background-image: url('../images/globe-hv.png');
   }
 }
```

It works in all the latest browsers but IE. The hover pseudo state does not trigger in IE. I have found a number of questions on Stackoverflow about this, but they are all older and have not provided a solution (yet), so I figured it might be worth asking again.

Note that both states have a background image defined. I have added z-index and tried an IMG tag instead of the DIV. I tried display:block and added background colors. I appreciate any new pointers. If nothing else, I will just use Javascript to add a regular CSS class upon hover.

Comment: I see that the HTML is invalid as well (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12982269/is-it-semantically-incorrect-to-put-a-div-or-span-inside-of-a-button/12982334), so I should probably fix that first ....

Comment: Is your question 'why isn't this Sass working' or 'why isn't this CSS working'? If the latter, and you can do it already in plain CSS, please add the [tag:sass] tag to your question. Otherwise, please share the compiled CSS instead of the Sass.

Comment: Potentially related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49378906/buttonhover-not-working-in-ie-11-compatibility-mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could be wrong since I don't have IE to test...

I'm guessing the button as a wrapper is the issue. I assume the button's hover state clobbers the div's hover state. Does it work if you remove the `<button>`?

Alternately does it work if you move the hover to the button?

```
 .globe-img {
   background-image: url('../images/globe.png');
   height: 50px;
   width: 50px;
 }
 button:hover .globe-img {
   background-image: url('../images/globe-hv.png');
 }
```

Comment: Yes, thanks, I figured as much. I got rid of the inner div and wrapped the button with a span. I put the :hover style on the button and it works fine in all browsers.